# openOrCreateDatabase() undefined in the fragment class

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am writing a code in which I place an fragment within an activity. Now in the OnCreate() function of the fragment class, I am not having error in the following code

```
public class HomePage_Fragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page,container,false);


}
```

}

ERROR:The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type HomePage_Fragment

The code is very simple and I have used the same commands many times, so I am sure the syntax is correct.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`openOrCreateDatabase(name, mode, factory)` method is in [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) class

Change this line

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);
```

into

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);
```

Comment: it worked, but can you please explain me why is it so ?

Comment: that method defined in Context class not Fragment..check here for more http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29