# Execute sqlite query and Alarmmanager

Tags: sql, sqlite, alarmmanager, resolve

I'm trying to execute a sqlite query with my AlarmManager, but I get this error:

> Cannot resolve method openOrCreateDatabase()

What can I do? Here is my code.

```
public class Alarma extends BroadcastReceiver {

private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String idOrder = intent.getStringExtra("idOrder");

        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Clients", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("estado","Delivered");
        cv.put("fechaEntrega",format2.format(new Date()));
        db.update("orders", cv, "idOrder= ?", new String[]{idPedido});
        db.close();


   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this, I think it contains the answer to your question. [try this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511031/openorcreatedatabase-undefined-in-the-fragment-class).